# View data from database using MVC & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to view list of items from database ( I am using Entity Framework).

My Repository method:

```
public List<string> getListOfItems(int i)
{
    return (from x in db.Items where x.ID == i select x.Text).ToList();
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var itemOutput = repo.getListOfItems(1); // I just put 1 since I didn't know how to specify "i" - However theoretically it should return first item in database but its not
    ViewBag.itemOutput = itemOutput ;

    return View();
}
```

Model:

```
public class items
{
    [Key]
    public int ID{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string quantity{ get; set; }
}
```

ItemModel:

```
public class itemModels
{ 
    public List<List<string>> itemData{ get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.itemOutput )
{
    <table id="t01">
        <tr>
            <td>@item.name</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: what is issue ?

Comment: it is not showing the items from the database. technically it should show first item (e.g. Camera)

Comment: Have you check data is retrive from the database,  have you check correct database is pointing?

Comment: yes - the data side is okay. the problem is with the view code?!

Comment: have you getting compilation error in view?

Comment: string' does not contain a definition for 'name'

Comment: than, try to replace with `<td>@item.name</td>` tp `<td>@item</td>`, actually it returns the list of string

Comment: Why are you not using a proper model here? Don't use the `ViewBag` unless you absolutely have to. If you don't know how to pass a model to your view, then you should go back to basics and follow some tutorials first.

Comment: Yes, 1) don't use ViewBag, 2) do use a ViewModel, 3) GetList(ID) will always return a list of 0 or 1 items.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. i am new to MVC and some of the tutorials used viewbag.. I'll read about ViewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer:

`ViewBag.itemOutput` is a `List<string>` which makes `item` a `string`.

Therefore, use `@item` instead of `@item.name` (as `string` does not have `.name` property) in your view:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.itemOutput )
{
    <table id="t01">
        <tr>
            <td>@item</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Also, to get the full list, you could do:

```
public List<string> getListOfItems()
{
    return (from x in db.Items select x.Text).ToList();
}
```

And then just call `getListOfItems()` with no param.

---

### Random comments:

1) Don't use plural for class name, *unless the class is somewhat a collection of things*

```
--> public class item // without s
```

2) You said in comments that `items` are full `varchar` which is untrue as per your class definition (you have `ID`, `name` & `quantity`).

3) Using `string` for `quantity` is a bit weird.

4) You could indeed change your `getListOfItems` method to:

```
public List<item> getListOfItems()
{
    return (from x in db.Items select x).ToList();
    // which can be simplified to:
    // return db.Items.ToList();
}
```

but you should then change your view back to `@item.name`.

This would however allow you to do:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.itemOutput )
{
    <table id="t01">
        <tr>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>@item.quantity</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

5) You have an `ItemModel` but you are not using it. You could modify it and use it instead of the `ViewBag`.

Comment: Great! :) it worked but at the moment in my controller, I've put      var itemOutput = repo.getListOfItems(1);  so its returning first item how can I instead loop through my items in my database table??

Comment: from x in db.Items where x.ID == i will return one item with the ID == 1. You are asking for a single item and returning it in a list.

Comment: @Warda I edited my answer to add the *get the full list* part

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! :)))

Comment: @Warda glad it helped you :) I edited my answer to add some comments

Answer (score 0):

getListOfItems() returns a list of string, but you're referring to an actual object in ViewBag.itemOutput

Instead of select x.Text do a select x, and make the return value `List<items>`

```
public List<items> getListOfItems(int i)
{
    return (from x in db.Items where x.ID == i select x).ToList();
}
```

Then you can keep your razor template the same to refer to @item.name

Comment: yeah the items in my database is varchar - all strings. so what do you suggest??

Comment: What I'm saying is your Razor template is trying to reference a full item, but you're only returning back strings from the repository.

Comment: @int21h is correct. Your action method and the view do not match.